# regarding well formed xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a main xsl and it contains separate references of two different xsl's as shown below but the issue is ThaT when I transform it throws an exception

please advise is that my main xsl is well formed or I am missing something..

```
    <xsl:import href="qwe.xsl"/>
    <xsl:import href="qrt.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/abml">
        <cfabcmessage>
            <defflows>
                <xsl:variable name="ttSystem">
                    <xsl:call-template name=ttSystem_template"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="ttSystem = 'ABC'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="dgddsh_ABC"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:call-template name="hjsgscjkd_DEG"/>
                </xsl:choose>
            </defflows>
        </cfabcmessage>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have done the corrections but still upon transformation I am stil getting this error..

```
21:03:34,892 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - xsl:when is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet!;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a double quote on the following line for the name attribute:

```
<xsl:call-template name="ttSystem_template"/>
```

Not sure if you just left the first line out, but you will need something like the following as well:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a double quote ahead of `ttSystem_template`, and you had the `xsl:call-template` between the close of the `xsl:when` and the close of the `xsl:choose`.  Move the `xsl:call-template` (1) within the `xsl:when`, (2) inside a `xsl:otherwise`, or (3) outside of the `xsl:choose`.  (You also were missing the opening `xsl:stylesheet` tag, but that was probably just a copy-and-paste error.)

**Here's a complete, corrected copy of your XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:import href="qwe.xsl"/>
  <xsl:import href="qrt.xsl"/>

  <xsl:template match="/abml">
    <cfabcmessage>
      <defflows>
        <xsl:variable name="ttSystem">
          <xsl:call-template name="ttSystem_template"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="ttSystem = 'ABC'">
            <xsl:call-template name="dgddsh_ABC"/>
            <!-- 1. Want call to hjsgscjkd_DEG it here? -->
            <xsl:call-template name="hjsgscjkd_DEG"/>
          </xsl:when>
            <!-- XXX  Call to hjsgscjkd_DEG cannot go here. -->
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- 2. Want call to hjsgscjkd_DEG it here? -->
            <xsl:call-template name="hjsgscjkd_DEG"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <!-- 3. Want call to hjsgscjkd_DEG it here? -->
        <xsl:call-template name="hjsgscjkd_DEG"/>
      </defflows>
    </cfabcmessage>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the new issue, it is not clear when you want to invoke the second 'call-template', but if this is supposed to be an 'else' condition then you need to use 'xsl:otherwise'

```
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="ttSystem = 'ABC'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="dgddsh_ABC"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="hjsgscjkd_DEG"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Ah, good point about the `xsl:otherwise` possibility.  +1, and I've updated my answer to reflect alternative placements inspired by your point.